# Packer's Ansible connection plugin fails for Windows

Tags: windows, ansible, packer

I need to create VM image with Packer and Ansible,
I use [ssh.py Ansible connection plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py) and it works fine with Linux
..but with Windows it fails:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Connected to WinRM!
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Ansible...
==> amazon-ebs: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook --extra-vars packer_build_name=amazon-ebs packer_builder_type=amazon-ebs -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible104051014 /opt/windows.yml -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/tmp/ansible-key358284483 --connection packer -vvv --extra-vars ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None
    amazon-ebs: ansible-playbook 2.9.2
    amazon-ebs:   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
    amazon-ebs:   configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
    amazon-ebs:   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
    amazon-ebs:   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
    amazon-ebs:   python version = 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    amazon-ebs: Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
    amazon-ebs: host_list declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible104051014 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs: script declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible104051014 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs: auto declined parsing /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible104051014 as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    amazon-ebs: Parsed /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible104051014 inventory source with ini plugin
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAYBOOK: windows.yml **********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: 1 plays in /opt/windows.yml
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    amazon-ebs: task path: /opt/windows.yml:2
    amazon-ebs: Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
    amazon-ebs: Pipelining is enabled.
    amazon-ebs: <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    amazon-ebs: <127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=40955 -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ansible-key358284483"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/473dfa98db 127.0.0.1 'chcp.com 65001 > $null ; PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand 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'
    amazon-ebs: <127.0.0.1> (1, '', "Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:40955' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nParameter format not correct - ;\r\n")
    amazon-ebs: <127.0.0.1> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:40955' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    amazon-ebs: Parameter format not correct - ;
    amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
    amazon-ebs:     "ansible_facts": {},
    amazon-ebs:     "changed": false,
    amazon-ebs:     "failed_modules": {
    amazon-ebs:         "setup": {
    amazon-ebs:             "failed": true,
    amazon-ebs:             "module_stderr": "Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:40955' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nParameter format not correct - ;\r\n",
    amazon-ebs:             "module_stdout": "",
    amazon-ebs:             "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    amazon-ebs:             "rc": 1
    amazon-ebs:         }
    amazon-ebs:     },
    amazon-ebs:     "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"
    amazon-ebs: }
    amazon-ebs:
    amazon-ebs: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    amazon-ebs: default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
    amazon-ebs:
```

Packer template:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "aws_access_key": "AKIAI7***CFTD7RA",
        "aws_secret_key": "bh8B***SptiOIWL"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
            "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
            "region": "us-east-1",
            "source_ami_filter": {
                "filters": {
                    "virtualization-type": "hvm",
                    "name": "Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base-*",
                    "root-device-type": "ebs"
                },
                "owners": [
                    "801119661308"
                ],
                "most_recent": true
            },
            "instance_type": "m4.large",
            "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}",
            "user_data_file": "./SetUpWinRM.ps1",
            "communicator": "winrm",
            "winrm_username": "Administrator",
            "winrm_timeout": "15m",
            "winrm_use_ssl": true,
            "winrm_insecure": true
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "ansible",
            "playbook_file": "./windows.yml",
            "extra_arguments": [
                "--connection",
                "packer",
                "-vvvv",
                "--extra-vars",
                "ansible_shell_type=powershell ansible_shell_executable=None"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: ping
    win_ping:
```

Runtime:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG PACKER_VERSION=1.5.1
ARG ANSIBLE_VERSION=2.9

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install wget unzip software-properties-common -y

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/${PACKER_VERSION}/packer_${PACKER_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip packer_${PACKER_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -f packer_${PACKER_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip

RUN  add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible-${ANSIBLE_VERSION} -y && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install ansible -y && \
    ansible --version

ADD . /opt
```

Any advice?

Comment: @Rekovni thanks a lot man, that's what fatigue means(